# How to count value type within a group with 0 if it is absent in the group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
id   value_type
1       b
1       a
1       a
2       a
3       a
3       b
```

I want to  count value type within a group with 0 if it is absent in group.so desired result is:

```
id   value_type       cnt
1       b             1
1       a             2
2       a             1
2       b             0
3       a             1
3       b             1
```

How could I do that? I tried groupby().size() but it counts without 0 if it is absent in group

Answer (score 1):

Try `.pivot_table` and then `.stack`:

```py
x = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index="id", columns="value_type", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0
    )
    .stack()
    .reset_index(name="cnt")
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   id value_type  cnt
0   1          a    2
1   1          b    1
2   2          a    1
3   2          b    0
4   3          a    1
5   3          b    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,1,2,3,3],'col2':['b','a','a','a','a','b']})

df_col1 = df[['col1']].drop_duplicates().assign(join_col = 1)

df_col2 = df[['col2']].drop_duplicates().assign(join_col = 1)

full_df = pd.merge(df_col1, df_col2,left_on='join_col', right_on='join_col').drop('join_col', axis=1)

final_df = pd.merge(full_df, df.assign(col3=df.col2), left_on=['col1','col2'], right_on=['col1','col2'], how='left').\
fillna(0)

final_df['count'] = np.where(final_df['col3']!=0,1, 0)

final_df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'count':'sum'}).reset_index().sort_values(['col1','count'])
```

Output:

[image]